# AngularJS - Directive to create conditional button cascading all attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to create an AngularJS directive which is able to create a custom button with **ng-if** based on a **trigger-event** attribute (binded and with dynamic value according to what the user do on the form) and cascading all the other attributes (***any***, not predictable) on the new button. The button will contain the same HTML of the myButton.

The trigger event condition is specified in the controller:

```
$scope.trigger = (specified in the controller and dynamic); // can be true or false
$scope.disabled = (specified in the controller and dynamic); // can be true or false
```

myButton will be something like this:

```
<my-button trigger-event="trigger" class="class" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="callback" any-other-attribute=[...]>
  <span>any html</span>
  <any-other-html></any-other-html>
</my-button>
```

The directive will be reflected in something like this:

```
<button ng-if="trigger-event" directive-to-trigger-event class="class" ng-disabled="disabled" any-other-attribute=[...]>
  <span>any html</span>
  <any-other-html></any-other-html>
</button>
<button ng-if="!trigger-event" type="submit" class="class" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="callback" any-other-attribute=[...]>
  <span>any html</span>
  <any-other-html></any-other-html>
</button>
```

The **directive-to-trigger-event** might be anything: something which launch a popup, something which reset a form, anything.

Anyone have idea on how to do this? Any hint will be really appreciated.

This is the idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/kHCoExQSTPssL294NUux?p=preview

Thank you!

Comment: could you please create a fiddle of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @chandings this is the idea, yes it's not working of course - http://plnkr.co/edit/kHCoExQSTPssL294NUux?p=preview

Comment: I have taken a fork of your plunkr and updated it with my understanding of what you need. Please tell me whats missing so that I can update it more.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Hk1AvRS3nN4YXqcLvZGR?p=preview

Comment: @chandings yes, it's more or less what I need :) Could you please explain me why the usage of $timeout? And also... how can I prevent the ngClick attribute to be copied to the button where the "trigger == true"?

Answer (score 0):

Directive to trigger any event can be created. On any event trigger there must be particular function going to execute in unique way.

So create one **Base scoped** controller and register required trigger event function with scope of that controller. Also pass one attribute which contains function parameters with same sequence as function declaration.

Create directive as you have mentioned which will be used linke below:

```
<my-button trigger-event="triggerFunctionName" class="class" other-attribute=[...]
         trigger-html-content="triggerHTMLPartialName">
     <span>any html</span>
     <any-other-html></any-other-html>
</my-button>
```

Create directive which is sharing base controller scope and compile HTML of template URL passed and update directive with transcluded mode and execute trigger function passed.

Comment: trigger-event is a boolean. If true one type of button is displayed, else another type of button is. I think you misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the directive is:

```
app.directive('myButton', function($timeout) {

  var tpl = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var btn = "<button ng-if='trigger'>"
            + "a<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>"
            + "</button>"
            + "<button ng-if='!trigger'>"
            + " <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>"
            + "</button>";
    return btn;
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: tpl,
    transclude:true,
    scope: {
      eventData: '=',
      trigger: '=triggerEventIf'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      scope.event = {
        'title': scope.eventData.title
      }

      var setAttributes = function(){
        for(var attribute in attrs){
          if(attribute !== 'triggerEventIf' && attribute.charAt(0) !== '$')
          angular.element(element[0].children).attr(attribute,attrs[attribute])

        }
      }

      scope.$watch('trigger', function(oldValue, newValue){
        if(oldValue !== newValue){
          $timeout(function(){
            setAttributes();
          });
        }
      })

      $timeout(function(){
        setAttributes();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

you can go to the link

http://plnkr.co/edit/Hk1AvRS3nN4YXqcLvZGR?p=preview

to see it in action.

The reason I am using $timeout is to ensure that setAttributes() is digested by angular properly. setAttributes is doing some DOM manipulation directly and this if not seen by angular properly may lead some strange behavior. $timeout function is the angular wrapper for timeout. But we are not giving it any time which basically means it needs to be called immediately. Angular ensures that the method of $timeout is properly digested by it. Thus it is a simple hack to ensures that it is properly digested.

directly calling $apply or $digest sometimes causes conflicts if a digest is in process. This is taken care of by $timeout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is cristal clear. I think there is one remaining issue: from the parent elememt <my-button></my-button> the attributes should be all removes, otherwise I will have for instance the "class" attributed applied to the outer element and the inner element as well.

Comment: I've tried with the "removeAttr()" but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: could you please update the plunkr so that i can work on it. n cheer up we will find a solution.